# Валидация и тест кейсы

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Мне нужно установить валидацию на длину текста в 10 символов (сейчас 50). Когда я изменяю на 10 - падает тест кейс, в котором указано 50. Как мне сделать валидацию, чтобы пройти этот тест кейс?

Код модели

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: films
#
#  id          :bigint           not null, primary key
#  description :text
#  name        :string
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#
class Film < ApplicationRecord
  MIN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 10
  MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 250

  validates :name, :description, presence: true
  validates :description,
            length: { minimum: MIN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH, maximum: MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH }
end
```

Тест кейсы

```
describe Film, type: :model do
  context 'validations' do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:description) }

    it 'validates description length' do
      expect(subject)
        .to validate_length_of(:description)
        .is_at_least(50)
        .is_at_most(described_class::MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Извините, но по логике, которая заложена в тесты, вам не надо делать валидцию на длинну в 10 символов.

Еслив тест кейсе написано 50 - значит, надо делать на 50.

Если надо сделать на 10 - то в тест кейсе должно быть 10.

Я правильно понимаю, что на тест кейсы Вы повлиять не можете? Может быть, тогда нужно связаться с человеком, который может на них повлиять, и убедить его, что в тест кейсе должно быть "10"?

Comment: Да не могу. Написано чтоб не изменять спецификацию тестов и поуляцию БД

Comment: Мне кажется, что в рамках этих условий и Вашей постановки задачи эта задача не решается. Было бы любопытно узнать, что я ошибаюсь. Но  тесте 50 прорписано просто как константа, и не зависит даже от переменных класса MIN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH и MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH